# question on django FileField handling and clean method

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a rather simple model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

which I can update via a form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop("product")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"] = forms.IntegerField()
        self.fields[product.data.keys()[0]] = forms.CharField()
        self.fields[product.data.keys()[1]] = forms.FileField()
            ...

     def clean(self):
         cleaned_data = super().clean()
         print(cleaned_data.get("image")) ## prints None
         print(self.files) ## prints:
```

which all works fine, I put the form in the template with an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set and then I receive the form in my `TemplateView`:

```
class ProductUpdateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "update_product.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = Product.objects.get(pk = kwargs["pk"])
        print(request.FILES) ## prints the correct filename!
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, product = obj)
        for key in request.POST.keys():
            ...
        obj.save()
        context = {'product': obj}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Why is `self.files` printing `None`, also `cleaned_data.get("image")` printing `<MultiValueDict: {}>`, but in the view, `request.FILES` correctly knows of `<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.png (image/png)>]}>`?

Comment: How do you use the form in the view?

Comment: I extended the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you need to properly use the form and construct it with:

```
ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, product=obj)
```